# C# System.Threading.Timer and its state object

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a C# program that uses System.Threading.Timer to timeout on a UDP socket ReceiveAsync call.

My program polls a remote device, sending a UDP packet and expecting one in return.

I use the timer in one shot mode calling Timer.Change every time I want a new timeout period.

For every occurance of a timeout I'd like the timeout handler to have a different piece of information.

If I change the object I pass to the Timer on creation it doesn't seem to change when the handler executes.

Is the only way to do this to destroy the timer and create a new one?

Thanks,

Comment: Too sad no one answered you

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing a struct instead of a class object?  Structs are value types, you'll get a copy back of the first version of it.  Changes you make will be lost since the state doesn't get passed by ref in the callback.  Using a class instead of a struct is the simple solution.

Storing the state object in your own class is another approach.

Comment: I just realized that that's not the real problem here.

The real problem is that I need to be able to pass state to the timer each time I do a single shot so that the state rides along with the completion packet.

Regardless of whether the timer makes a copy of the state I pass to it or uses the original one it won't let you pass a new one for each run without destroying and remaking the timer (something I am loath to do).

Comment: Well, if you use a reference type as the object then you *can* change the state of that object.  I'm probably missing something because I don't see or ever had any use for the object.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter if you can pass the object in because you can only select one for the entire timer. What you really want is one for every time you run the timer once. Now what I do is I only use the timer to give me the opportunity to check another time (taken with Environment.TickCount). If that time exceeds my timeout period only then do I take the timeout action. It's not as pretty but it does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this cheap wrapper:

```
sealed class TimerWrapper : IDisposable
{
    readonly Timer timer;

    object State { get; set; }

    public TimerWrapper(TimerCallback callback) 
    {
        timer = new Timer(delegate { callback(State); });
    }

    public void Change(object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
    {
        timer.Change(dueTime, period);
        State = state;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Please note that using the code above can lead to unexpected behaviour in some rare race conditions.

Comment: I have a race between an on IO complete callback and the timer that's meant to tell me that my IO didn't finish on time.

It's possible for the timer event to be posted to the execute queue and before it gets to execute my IO completes.

In that case, because I start a new IO upon completion of the old one, the new IO gets terminated by a false timeout.

If the timeout event could carry the ID of the IO operation with it then even if this rare condition occurs it'll know not to terminate the current IO operation.

Is that the rare race condition you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The object you pass could be an array with a single element that you replace on each timeout.

Answer (score 0):

use WaitHandle and lock to synchronize